# What explicit things need to be taken care of when moving J2EE application from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, exception, tomcat7

My J2EE application has been moved from Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7. Most of the JSPs are working fine. However one of the JSPs give the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.AbstractMethodError
type Exception report

message java.lang.AbstractMethodError

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    com.mitel.npm.web.console.jsp.editCDTemplate_jsp._jspService(editCDTemplate_jsp.java:203)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)
    org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    com.mitel.npm.web.console.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:16)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.isAsyncStarted(ServletRequestWrapper.java:396)
    com.mitel.npm.web.console.jsp.editCDTemplate_jsp._jspService(editCDTemplate_jsp.java:166)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1056)     org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:261)     org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:388)       org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:316)      org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:231)        org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:397)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)        com.mitel.npm.web.console.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:16)     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I checked for mismatch in Jar files in Tomcat directory and WEB-INF/lib
but there were no duplicate JARS:

Tomcat 7 JARS:

```
annotations-api-7.0.57.jar
annotations-api.jar
catalina-7.0.57.jar
catalina-ant-7.0.57.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha-7.0.57.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina.jar
catalina-tribes-7.0.57.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
ecj-4.4-7.0.57.jar
ecj-4.4.jar
jasper-7.0.57.jar
jasper-el-7.0.57.jar
jasper-el.jar
jasper.jar
tomcat7-el-2.2-api-7.0.57.jar
tomcat7-jsp-2.2-api-7.0.57.jar
tomcat7-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.57.jar
tomcat7-websocket-7.0.57.jar
tomcat7-websocket.jar
tomcat-api-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
tomcat-juli-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-juli-extras-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-juli-extras.jar
tomcat-juli.jar
tomcat-util-7.0.57.jar
tomcat-util.jar
websocket-api-7.0.57.jar
websocket-api.jar
```

Application WEB-INF/lib JARS:

```
activation.jar
axis-ant.jar
axis.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-discovery.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-validator.jar
dwr.jar
httpunit-1.6.jar
jaxen-full.jar
jaxrpc.jar
jdom.jar
js.jar
junit.jar
jwebunit-1.2.jar
log4j-1.2.8.jar
mail.jar
nekohtml-0.8.1.jar
npm-admin.jar
org.apache.commons.lang.jar
pja.jar
saaj.jar
saxpath.jar
soap.jar
struts.jar
strutstest-2.1.2.jar
wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
wsdl4j.jar
xmlrpc-1.2-b1.jar
```

The JSP for reference:
Edited:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/tags/struts-bean" prefix="bean"%>    
<%@ page import="web.shared.*" %>
<%@ page import="web.console.taglib.*" %>
<script language="Javascript"><!--
//--></script>
<%
MenuState menuState = (MenuState)request.getSession().getAttribute( MenuTag.MENU_STATE );
if (menuState != null) {
    menuState.setCurrentMenuId( MenuTag.TEMPLATE_LEAF );
}
%>

<console:page url="emptyPage.jsp">
  <console:menu>
  </console:menu>

  <console:pageBody>
     <!--  some basic code here -->

  </console:pageBody>
</console:page>
```

Comment: Additional information: the code was compiled with Java 6 , Tomcat 6 libraries and being deployed on Tomcat 7.

Comment: If you suspect duplicated classes, that can be hard to find. One of your app's or tomcat's jars could have repackaged another library without changing class names.  Here is a migration guide with potential issues: http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html - I would guess the cause is either servlet, jsp, el or xml api.

Comment: @kapep I have re checked the 4 apis mentioned by you but I am unable to find the conflict.